# Get aspect ratio (width and height) of an uploaded image

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to validate my image upload in my API. I want only allow photos which are in landscape mode. I would also like to check the aspect ratio. This is my code for checking if the iFormFile is an image:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Post(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/jpeg" &&
            file.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/jpg" &&
            file.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/png")
        {
            // not a .jpg or .png file
            return new JsonResult(new
            {
                success = false
            });
        }

        // todo: check aspect ratio for landscape mode

        return new JsonResult(new
        {
            success = true
        });
    }
```

Since `System.Drawing.Image` is not available anymore, I couldn't find a way to convert the iFormFile into an Image typed object, to check the width and height to calculate the aspect ratio of it. How can I get the width and height of an image with the type iFormFile in ASP.NET Core API 2.0?

Comment: You shouldn't render a file just to get its dimensions, use an image library like SoftImaging to extract the dimensions from the file.

Comment: @DourHighArch You shouldn't render a file just to get its dimensions - that's maybe right, but using a third party library just to do a simple dimension check on an image? - I don't think that's the way to go.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Since `System.Drawing.Image` is not available anymore, I couldn't find a way to convert the iFormFile into an Image typed object, to check the width and height to calculate the aspect ratio of it.

That's actually not correct. Microsoft has released `System.Drawing.Common` as a [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common), which provides cross-platform GDI+ graphics functionality. The API should be an in-place replacement for any old `System.Drawing` code:

```
using (var image = Image.FromStream(file.OpenReadStream()))
{
    // use image.Width and image.Height
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that it got moved out to a NuGet package. It works!

Comment: The nuget-package has external depencies:
https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/documentation/scenarios/using-system-drawing-common.md

Comment: Well, yes, and no. System.Drawing is a GDI+ graphics library, so you obviously need those components. The issue addressed by that link is for containers, which are running stripped down OS images, so yeah, you have to install the components there.

Comment: So I install this yet still CA1416 is still thrown by VS

Comment: This only works on Windows. I suggest you use the SixLabors.ImageSharp library.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in .net core and I solved it by a **client side solution**. Based on your project conditions, You may trust in client side processing and let them to do some jobs. You can get the aspect ratio with some lines of js code which is [supported on all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL#Browser_compatibility) and then passing those (`width` & `height`) to API as well:

```
var file = e.target.files[0];
if (/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = this.result as string;
        image.addEventListener('load', function () {
            console.log(`height: ${this.height}, width: ${this.width}`);
        });
                
    }, false);
            
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

And API will look like:

```
//POST : api/samples?width=100&height=500
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Post(IFormFile file, int width, int height) {}
```

I've tested this solution for *multiple file upload* and works fine.

Comment: And what if I send request as "api/samples?width=10&height=10" with an image which is actually 1000x1000 ? Your solution works only if we can trust all incoming traffic and have access to front-end sources